# Why [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'data/mt_bench/question.jsonl' was appeared when implementing MT-Bench?

Tags: python, github

I am trying to implement MT-Bench in my Colab notebook, however I have encountered a problem that I cannot solve.

I tried to follow the code in [GitHub lm-sys FastChat  LLM Judge](https://github.com/lm-sys/FastChat/tree/main/fastchat/llm_judge#llm-judge).
However, Python threw a `FileNotFoundError` exception when running it.

```
python gen_model_answer.py --model-path lmsys/fastchat-t5-3b-v1.0 --model-id fastchat-t5-3b-v1.0
```

The specific error of above code is as follows:

```
Output to data/mt_bench/model_answer/fastchat-t5-3b-v1.0.jsonl
╭───────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ──────────────────────╮
│ /content/FastChat/fastchat/llm_judge/gen_model_answer.py:236 in <module>     │
│                                                                              │
│   233 │                                                                      │
│   234 │   print(f"Output to {answer_file}")                                  │
│   235 │                                                                      │
│ ❱ 236 │   run_eval(                                                          │
│   237 │   │   args.model_path,                                               │
│   238 │   │   args.model_id,                                                 │
│   239 │   │   question_file,                                                 │
│                                                                              │
│ /content/FastChat/fastchat/llm_judge/gen_model_answer.py:33 in run_eval      │
│                                                                              │
│    30 │   num_gpus_total,                                                    │
│    31 │   max_gpu_memory,                                                    │
│    32 ):                                                                     │
│ ❱  33 │   questions = load_questions(question_file, question_begin, question │
│    34 │   # random shuffle the questions to balance the loading              │
│    35 │   random.shuffle(questions)                                          │
│    36                                                                        │
│                                                                              │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastchat/llm_judge/common.py:86 in   │
│ load_questions                                                               │
│                                                                              │
│    83 def load_questions(question_file: str, begin: Optional[int], end: Opti │
│    84 │   """Load questions from a file."""                                  │
│    85 │   questions = []                                                     │
│ ❱  86 │   with open(question_file, "r") as ques_file:                        │
│    87 │   │   for line in ques_file:                                         │
│    88 │   │   │   if line:                                                   │
│    89 │   │   │   │   questions.append(json.loads(line))                     │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'data/mt_bench/question.jsonl'
```

Why has this error been thrown and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Seems this code was written with a virtual environment in mind, since `question_file` is defined relatively to the base folder of the project. Try using a virtual environment or change the file path to the absolute path to it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, an error erupted again, when using the absolute path '/content/FastChat/fastchat/llm_judge/gen_model_answer.py'  

Comment: Is that the _full_ absolute path, and not one from your home directory? Try using `realpath gen_model_answer.py` inside the directory the file is located.